# Return new array of two differents types of arrays according their Id

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have two differents arrays with those models

```
export interface ProfileMaterialCategory{
  id?: string
  materialCategory_Name?: string
  materialCategory_Id: string
  quantity: string
  profileId?: string
}
```

And

```
import { Category } from "./material-asset-model";

export interface UserAssetsCount {
  category: Category
  userAssetsCount: number;
}
```

In my .ts file I'm trying to create a method for getting a combined records for all matching materialCategory_Id / category.Id.

The returned array must have this syntax

```
[category.name:string, userAssetsCount:string, quantity:string]
```

I tried with filter and includes but it his not working, or I don't take the problem correctly.

This is the arguments that the method takes.

```
    GetMatch(profileAssets: ProfileMaterialCategory[], userAssets: UserAssetsCount[]): Object[] {
       
    var filteredArray = userAssetsAllowed.filter(
      as

setAllowed => userAssetsCount.some(
  assetCount => assetCount.category.id.toString() == assetAllowed.materialCategory_Id)

return filteredArray
}
```

When I filter, I receive an element of the array when the condition is true, but it's an element from one of the array, I can't take value from the other.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've succed in one way to do what I needed.
First I created a new DTO model:

```
export interface UserAssetMatch {
  category: Category,
  allowed: string,
  owned: number
}
```

Then I make a foreach() loop on one array, and use a filter() on the second array. I keep the matching elements in an intermediate array.
If there is something in the intermediate array, I push the informations that I need in the DTO.

```
GetMatch(userAssetsAllowed: ProfileMaterialCategory[], userAssetsCount: UserAssetsCount[]): UserAssetMatch[] {

    var matchArray: UserAssetMatch[] = [];

    userAssetsCount.forEach(userAsset => {
      var profileAssets = userAssetsAllowed.filter(userAssetAllowed => userAsset.category.id.toString() == userAssetAllowed.materialCategory_Id);
      if (profileAssets.length > 0) {
        matchArray.push({
          category: userAsset.category,
          owned: userAsset.userAssetsCount,
          allowed: profileAssets[0].quantity
        })
      }
    });
    return matchArray;
```

I don't think it is a good way to do, but it works. If someone have a better/faster/cleaner way to do, please tell me :)